# Ignore case for object properties when comparing collections

Tags: c#, fluent-assertions

I have two collections that contain objects of my custom type.
I compare these collections using FluentAssertions library:

```
Collection1.Should().BeEquivalentTo(Collection2);
```

Let's say, objects in the collections have string property called `Title`, but sometimes their case is different (title case vs. upper case). The comparison fails due to this.

Is there a way to ignore case for some (or all) object's string properties when comparing collections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, sorry. But you could create your own implementation of [IMemberSelectionRule](https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions/blob/develop/Src/Core/Equivalency/IMemberMatchingRule.cs)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I found a way to make these string properties `ToUpper()` on collection initialization, so the case does not matter.

Comment: Wait, you meant that the casing of the actual property _values_ had different casing. I thought you meant the names of the properties.

Comment: No, case of property values. The names are always 'Title'.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Just make your custom type implement `IComparable` interface. In `CompareTo` method implement a comparison whatever way you want. In your case, a ignore-case string comparison.